# Chrome DevTools font has been changed to Monospace after update

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

After Chrome 123 update, my DevTools font has been changed to 'Monospace'. Is there any way to rollback my DevTools font to any readable font?

[image: Monospace font in Chrome DevTools]

I've tried using [DevTools Font Changer](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/devtools-font-changer/fikbcnlbgoafooldbkgikejejhaddajg). But it didn't changed my console font:

[image: Monospace font still in Chrome DevTools console input]

Comment: It's a bug in devtools. Probably platform-specific as I don't see it in Windows.

Comment: I am using windows 11... I think I need to reinstall chrome then

Comment: The bug may be triggered by regional settings in Windows, mine are English. See also https://crbug.com/330760882

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try change "Fixed-width font" to a comfortable font in chrome://settings/fonts.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmAsB.png)